# Decreasing the size of an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm really confused on this aspect. Each of the squares in the image contains a number of pixels where some of the squares are bigger, for example one square might have a width of 9 and a height of 8 whereas another one has a width of 7 and a height of 8. What I'm trying to do is create a smaller image from this initial image where each square represents a pixel and all the pixels would be the same size.

[image]

I've done it for the greyscale image but unfortunately, I get the wrong result i.e. the resulting image is not an exact copy of the input image

Input image

[image]

Output image

[image]

Code for greyscale image

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

name1 = raw_input("What is the name of the .png file you want to open? ")

filename1 = "%s.png" % name1

img = Image.open(filename1).convert('L')  # convert image to 8-bit grayscale
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size

a = list(img.getdata()) # convert image data to a list of integers
# convert that to 2D list (list of lists of integers)
a = np.array ([a[offset:offset+WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH*HEIGHT, WIDTH)])

print " "
print "Intial array from image:"  #print as array
print " "
print a

rows_mask = np.insert(np.diff(a[:, 0]).astype(np.bool), 0, True)
columns_mask = np.insert(np.diff(a[0]).astype(np.bool), 0, True)
b = a[np.ix_(rows_mask, columns_mask)]

print " "
print "Subarray from Image:"  #print as array
print " "
print b

print " "
print "Subarray from Image (clearer format):"  #print as array
print " "
for row in b: #print as a table like format
    print(' '.join('{:3}'.format(value) for value in row))

img = Image.fromarray(b, mode='L')

img.save("chocolate.png")


#print np.mean(b) #finding mean
```

Comment: You already know that the sizes of each enlarged pixel are different – but I see nothing in your code that attempt to address that?

Comment: I put the wrong code in by mistake. I've updated it now. Doesn't `b = a[np.ix_(rows_mask, columns_mask)]` address that? I'm a newbie, forgive me if I'm not doing it right

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50924974/7328782 Did the two answers there not solve your problem?

Comment: Not really, I thought I didn't make it clear on that question thats probably why they misunderstood it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a greyscale image to a smaller 'pixel by pixel' greyscale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924974/converting-a-greyscale-image-to-a-smaller-pixel-by-pixel-greyscale-image)