# Bilinear interpolation with non-aligned input points

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I have a non-grid-aligned set of input values associated with grid-aligned output values. Given a new input value I want to find the output:

[image: Four points in a rectangle with inputs varying on each axis, but outputs representing rectangular inputs.]

(These are X,Y coordinates, calibrating an imprecise not-square eye-tracking input device to exact locations on screen.)

This looks like [Bilinear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation), but my input values are not grid-aligned. Given an input, how can I figure out a reasonable output value?

---

**Answer**: In this case where I have sets of input and output points, what is actually needed is to perform [inverse bilinear interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808441/inverse-bilinear-interpolation) to find the U,V coordinates of the input point within the quad, and then perform normal bilinear interpolation (as described in Nico's answer below) on the output quad using those U,V coordinates.

Comment: Can you assume linearity? Should rotation be allowed/needed?

Comment: @wildplasser As noted by the red numbers in the diagram, the values may be skewed as a parallelogram, or trapezoid, but not rotated. Imagine a projector pointing at a screen off-axis.

Comment: Ah sorry, I had not checked the exact values. BTW: why not just .5 pixel for both X and Y and rounding down (or up for the opposite corner)

Comment: I only named it a pixel for convinience. The discretisation/quantisation seems the same to me.

Comment: @wildplasser I apologize, but I do not understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can bilinearly interpolate in any convex tetragon. A cartesian grid is just a bit simpler because the calculation of interpolation parameters is trivial. In the general case you interpolate as follows:

```
parameters alpha, beta
interpolated value = (1 - alpha) * ((1 - beta) * p1 + beta * p2) + alpha * ((1 - beta) * p3 + beta * p4)
```

In order to calculate the parameters, you have to solve a system of equations. Put your input values in the places of `p1` through `p4` and solve for `alpha` and `beta`.

Then put your output values in the places of `p1` through `p4` and use the calculated parameters to calculate the final interpolated output value.

For a regular grid, the parameter calculation comes down to:

```
alpha = x / cell width
beta  = y / cell height
```

which automatically solves the equations.

Here is a sample interpolation for `alpha=0.3` and `beta=0.6`

[image: Sample interpolation]

Actually, the equations can be solved analytically. However, the formulae are quite ugly. Therefore, iterative methods are probably nicer. There are two solutions for the system of equations. You need to pick the solution where both parameters are in [0, 1].

First solution:

```
alpha = -(b e - a f + d g - c h + sqrt(-4 (c e - a g) (d f - b h) +
        (b e - a f + d g - c h)^2))/(2 c e - 2 a g)    
beta  = (b e - a f - d g + c h + sqrt(-4 (c e - a g) (d f - b h) + 
        (b e - a f + d g - c h)^2))/(2 c f - 2 b g)
```

where

```
a = -p1.x + p3.x
b = -p1.x + p2.x
c = p1.x - p2.x - p3.x + p4.x
d = interpolated_point.x - p1.x
e = -p1.y + p3.y
f = -p1.y + p2.y
g = p1.y - p2.y - p3.y + p4.y
h = interpolated_point.y - p1.y
```

Second solution:

```
alpha = (-b e + a f - d g + c h + sqrt(-4 (c e - a g) (d f - b h) + 
        (b e - a f + d g - c h)^2))/(2 c e - 2 a g)
beta  = -((-b e + a f + d g - c h + sqrt(-4 (c e - a g) (d f - b h) + 
        (b e - a f + d g - c h)^2))/( 2 c f - 2 b g))
```

Comment: It's a general interpolation scheme. You can interpolate anything - be it a single value, a vector or entire tensors. I don't completely get your scenario, so I can't tell if bilinear interpolation suits your needs, but you asked for it. The parameters are usually calculated with the system of equations. Since it's not linear, iterative methods are your friend. Actually it's the other way around than you stated. You already know the intersection and need to find the parameters that lead to this intersection.

Comment: Thank you for this. As shown in the diagram I put in my answer, you are right, this is nicely general purpose. :) FWIW I put a fun little experiment up to see what happens with concave tetragons, to test rotations, and more: http://phrogz.net/tmp/bilinear-colors.html

Comment: Is there a typo in the expression for beta?  The denominator contains the term (cf-bg) so I think the expression inside the square root should also contain this term. I make the term inside the square root (-4(de-ah)(cf-bg) +(be-af-dg-ch)^2)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I think I mostly get it and it seems to be applicable to 3D as well. Am I right that in 3D your systems for solving alpha and beta would be over specified?

Comment: Just looked at this again and I think the term inside the square root should be (-4(de-ah)(cf-bg) +(be-af-dg+ch)^2).  There was a typo in my previous suggested correction  - apologies!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my own technique, along with code for deriving the resulting value. It requires three [lerps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) of the output values (and three percentage calculations to determine the lerp percentages):

**Note that this is not bilinear interpolation.** It does not remap the quad of input points to the quad of output values, as **some input points can result in output values outside the output quad**.

Here I'm showing the non-aligned input values on a Cartesian plane (using the sample input values from the question above, multiplied by 10 for simplicity).

[image]

To calculate the 'north' point (top green dot), we calculate the percentage across the X axis as

```
  (inputX - northwestX) / (northeastX - northwestX)
= (-4.2 - -19) / (10 - -19)
= 0.51034
```

We use this percentage to calculate the intercept at the Y axis by lerping between the top Y values:

```
  (targetValue - startValue) * percent + startValue
= (northeastY  - northwestY) * percent + northwestY
= (-8 - -7) * 0.51034 + -7
= -7.51034
```

We do the same on the 'south' edge:

```
  (inputX - southwestX) / (southeastX - southwestX)
= (-4.2 - -11) / (9 - -11)
= 0.34

  (southeastY - southwestY) * percent + southwestY
= (7 - 4) * 0.34 + 4
= 5.02
```

Finally, we use these two values to calculate the final percentage between the north and south edges:

```
  (inputY - southY) / (northY - southY)
= (1 - 5.02) / (-7.51034 - 5.02)
= 0.3208
```

With these three percentages in hand we can calculate our final output values by lerping between the points:

```
nw = Vector(-150,-100)
ne = Vector( 150,-100)
sw = Vector(-150, 100)
se = Vector( 150, 100)

north  = lerp( nw, ne, 0.51034)       --> (  3.10, -100.00)
south  = lerp( sw, se, 0.34)          --> (-48.00,  100.00)
result = lerp( south, north, 0.3208)  --> (-31.61,   35.84)
```

---

Finally, here is some (Lua) code performing the above. It uses a mutable Vector object that supports the ability to copy values from another vector and lerp its values towards another vector.

```lua
-- Creates a bilinear interpolator
-- Corners should be an object with nw/ne/sw/se keys,
-- each of which holds a pair of mutable Vectors
-- { nw={inp=vector1, out=vector2}, … }
function tetragonalBilinearInterpolator(corners)
  local sides = {
    n={ pt=Vector(), pts={corners.nw, corners.ne} },
    s={ pt=Vector(), pts={corners.sw, corners.se} }
  }

  for _,side in pairs(sides) do
    side.minX = side.pts[1].inp.x
    side.diff = side.pts[2].inp.x - side.minX
  end

  -- Mutates the input vector to hold the result
  return function(inpVector)
    for _,side in pairs(sides) do
      local pctX = (inpVector.x - side.minX) / side.diff
      side.pt:copyFrom(side.pts[1].inp):lerp(side.pts[2].inp,pctX)
      side.inpY = side.pt.y
      side.pt:copyFrom(side.pts[1].out):lerp(side.pts[2].out,pctX)
    end
    local pctY = (inpVector.y-sides.s.inpY)/(sides.n.y-sides.s.inpY)
    return inpVector:copyFrom(sides.s.pt):lerp(sides.n.pt,pctY)
  end
end

local interp = tetragonalBilinearInterpolator{
  nw={ inp=Vector(-19,-7),  out=Vector(-150,-100) },
  ne={ inp=Vector( 10,-8),  out=Vector( 150,-100) },
  sw={ inp=Vector(-11, 4),  out=Vector(-150, 100) },
  se={ inp=Vector(  9, 7),  out=Vector( 150, 100) }
}
print(interp(Vector(-4.2, 1))) --> <-31.60 35.84>
```

Comment: And now there's a JavaScript implementation on this test page I wrote: http://phrogz.net/tmp/bilinear-colors.html

Comment: It's fine if it fits your needs. But please don't call it bilinear interpolation. It is not. E.g. to determine a point near the top left corner would require an extrapolation of the bottom edge. Nice sample, by the way.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't understand your comment, and would love more information.

Comment: Well, first point, it's not a bilinear interpolation. That's just a question of definition. Nothing to argue about. Secondly, how would you determine the value at say `(-15, -6)` with your scheme? You would have to find a point on the bottom line with `x=-15`. But there is no point on this line (which would be interpolation), but there is a point on the line's extension. Sou you have to guess how the line would continue, which is called extrapolation.

Comment: @NicoSchertler My question was what part of the 'definition' makes my solution incompatible. However, I think that I finally understand. For my problem I want to perform [inverse bilinear interpolation](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/ibilinear/ibilinear.htm) on my inputs to find the alpha/beta values (u,v), and then use bilinear  interpolation on the output values using those to come up with the desired output.